# API request initiated by polyfills.bundle.js

Tags: angular, api, polyfills

whenever I make a API request from my angular2 app, I see there were two requests made in the browser console. The first one, I believe is an internal XHR request initiated by `polyfills.bundle.js` and the second one is the actual API call to return the response. I also note that these are not asynchronous calls. I see the first call initiated by `polyfills.bundle.js` is costing application performance. what is the purpose of this request? Is there a way I can skip the call initiated by `polyfills.ts`?[image]

Answer (score 0):

That might be a preflight request if it is crossdomain that happens